# All cash change is only for one bill

Tags: python

All money amount is going to one bill. Example: sum is 1550, but it's going to 4x500 bill with -50 balance. What I need to change in this code? Do I need to add percents where "price" is? Don't pay attention to how large bills are. I have tried to make `sk%10 == 0`, but it didn't worked.

```
a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
e=0
f=0

sk=0
sk=int(input("Enter money quanty: "))
if 10 <= sk:
    if sk >= 500:
        while 0 < sk:
            sk = sk - 500
            a = a + 1
    if sk >= 200:
        while 0 < sk:
            sk = sk - 200
            b = b + 1
    if sk >= 100:
        while 0 < sk:
            sk = sk - 100
            c = c + 1

    if sk >= 50:
        while 0 < sk:
            sk = sk - 50
            d = d + 1

    if sk >= 20:
        while 0 < sk:
            sk = sk - 20
            e = e + 1

    if sk >= 10:
        while 0 < sk:
            sk = sk - 10
            f = f + 1
    print("Bill list:")
    print("500 USD x", a)
    print("200 USD x", b)
    print("100 USD x", c)
    print("50 USD x", d)
    print("20 USD x", e)
    print("10 USD x", f)


else:
    print("Too small cash return")
```

Comment: Can you include the part of code that you're having trouble with in this question, and clarify what isn't working?

Comment: All money ammont is going to one bill

Comment: _seriously_ atrocious variable names. Try something descriptive!

Comment: If you `print sk` within each of your `while` loops, I suspect you'll notice quite quickly what isn't working. Part of the reason for homework is for you to work out why code isn't working, not just to get the right answer ;) **How can you keep `sk` from going to a negative balance?**

Comment: Tried everything.... I'm working all day with this code...

Comment: Huh.. Why print is showing me 2 different numbers... Tired 560 and got 60 and -440. But still I don't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's start with variable names that mean something; instead of `a` make it `fivehundreds`, instead of `b` make it `twohundreds`, etc.

Now your code starts to look like

```
if amount >= 500:
    while 0 < amount:
        amount -= 500
        fivehundreds += 1
```

which reads, "while amount is greater than 0 repeatedly subtract five hundred". So if amount is (for example) $37 - greater than $0 - you subtract, and now have one $500 bill and $-463 remaining. Instead, try

```
if 500 <= amount:
    while 500 <= amount:
        amount -= 500
        fivehundreds += 1
```

I rearranged the `if` condition to emphasize that it is redundant - if the `if` fails, the `while` wouldn't have done anything anyway. Let's get rid of that `if`. The same is true of your initial `if 10 <= sk`; if it fails, all of the `while` conditions would have failed anyway.

Now, with a bit of rearranging, your code looks like

```
fivehundreds = 0
while 500 <= amount:
    amount -= 500
    fivehundreds += 1
print("500 USD x", fivehundreds)

twohundreds = 0
while 200 <= amount:
    amount -= 200
    twohundreds += 1
print("200 USD x", twohundreds)

onehundreds = 0
while 100 <= amount:
    amount -= 100
    onehundreds += 1
print("100 USD x", onehundreds)
```

... you may notice a certain amount of similarity in these operations! This is usually a sign that you should use a loop. We want to do this with 500s, then 200s, then 100s, etc...

```
for denom in [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10]:
    num_bills = 0
    while amount >= denom:
        amount -= denom
        num_bills += 1
    print(denom, "USD x", num_bills)
```

Now there is one more change to make: instead of using a `while` loop to inch our way up to the right number of bills, we can use the `//` (integer divison) and `%` (modulus) operators to get the answer directly. I am also going to make the `print` statement optional - if we have 0 $500 bills, we don't really need to be told about it.

```
amount = int(input("How many dollars? "))

print("Bill list:")
for denom in [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10]:
    num_bills = amount // denom     # integer division
    amount %= denom                 # get remainder
    if num_bills:
        print("{} USD x {}".format(denom, num_bills))

if amount:
    print("Remainder: {} dollars".format(amount))
```

Comment: That's a very fine explanation. In the next step you could use [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) for the integer division and the remainder.